# Why no promotion when adding ints to List<Double>

Tags: java, integer-promotion

in Java I created an ArrayList of Double and I invoked the method list.add(1), however, I get an error.  If I can assign an int to a double variable like this:  double num = 1;  due to automatic promotion, then why can't I add a 1 to ArrayList of Double via automatic promotion?

Comment: What is the type of your ArrayList? Can you show the code?

Comment: Why are you not adding `1.0` or using `List<Integer>`?

Comment: `public Double makeDouble(int n) { return n + 0.0D }`

Comment: Sorry, I want to clarify that the ArrayList is:  ArrayList<Double>, I wonder why the diamond bracket part of my question got deleted.  It seems that ArrayList<Double> got truncated to ArrayList in my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not trying to convert `int` to `double`; you're trying to convert `int` to `Double`, which is a combination of boxing *and* the implicit conversion from `int` to `double`. That doesn't work, even in a simple assignment:

```
// Error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Double
Double num = 1;
```

It doesn't even work for `Long` - you need to specify a `long` literal:

```
Long num1 = 1; // Invalid
Long num2 = 1L; // Valid
```

In your case, you just need to use a `double` literal, e.g.

```
list.add(1.0);
list.add(1D);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the reason why I can't put a 1 for example in an ArrayList<Double>, it's because 1 can't be boxed into Double.